# jQuery delay for menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Could someone explain how to make delay for dropdown when mouse is out from #categories_block_top .tree ul ? Sorry but I am newbie at jQuery. Here is the link - http://livedemo04.prestatrend.com/ and js-file fot the menu is treeManagementTop.js.

Comment: You should post some code in the question. Especially for future visitors, it's helpful to see the code here because the link you provided may not always be a stable source for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you used hoverIntent plugin and you got an error "makeTall is not defined", check if you added that function
e.g. in the source of hoverIntent homepage it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo1 li").hover(makeTall,makeShort);
        $("#demo2 li").hoverIntent(makeTall,makeShort);
        $("#demo3 li").hoverIntent({
            over: makeTall, 
            timeout: 500, 
            out: makeShort
        });
    }); // close document.ready

    function makeTall(){  $(this).animate({"height":75},200);}
    function makeShort(){ $(this).animate({"height":50},200);}
</script>
```

But I did it another way without plugin:

```
 <ul id="elem">
<li><a href="#"><span>1</span></a>
<ul id="child" style="display:none;">
   <li ><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <li ><a href="">About</a></li>
       <li ><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
       <li ><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
 </ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $('#elem').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#ch').css('display', 'block');
   });
   $('#elem').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#ch').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
   });
    });
 </script>
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQueryElement.find('ul:first').stop(true,true).hide(100);
jQueryElement.find('ul:first').stop(true,true).slideUp(100);
```

These 2 lines: You can adjust the menu speed to be slower by increasing the 100 to a higher number.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add a delay see these:
[Jquery - Delay mouseout event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267402/jquery-delay-mouseout-event)
[Fade out jQuery menu after delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457626/fade-out-jquery-menu-after-delay)

Comment: Just added this plugin but there is an error - makeTall is not defined What the problem?

Comment: Which plugin did you add? Did this just happening once you loaded it?

Comment: jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js yes, it happening once I loaded it. http://livedemo04.prestatrend.com/

Comment: have you tried the setTimeout? `mouseout: function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $c('hide!');
    hideUnderConstruction();
  }, 500);
}`

Comment: I have never user the hoverIntent plugin, so I can't help with that.

Comment: hmm looks like the best option might be .delay() See: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I also think so, but I am do not understanding why at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089246/jquery-how-to-tell-hover-to-wait this plugin is more best way!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery hoverIntent plugin:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Just added this plugin but there is an error - makeTall is not defined What the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing one of the required functions. If you don't require the "makeTall" function, just pass it an empty function definition. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196429/plugging-in-jquery-hoverintent-for-sliding-panel

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the hoverIntent plugin lets you define some vars that help with mouseenter/out interactions: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Just added this plugin but there is an error - makeTall is not defined What the problem?